# Prove or disprove, all eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are non-negative.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I tried to find an answer for this question, but what I found was a classification of general matrices (i.e. definite, semi-definite and indefinite). I want to know more specifically about symmetric matrices.

Comment: Did you try to see what this says for $1\times1$ matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at a $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrix with $1$ and $-1$ on the diagonal.

Comment: ... or a $1\times 1$ diagonal matrix with $-1$ on the diagonal ...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What is the simplest subset of symmetric matrices you can think of (especially when it comes to determining eigenvalues)? Do any of those have negative eigenvalues?